# How to format PHP SSH2 read() output?

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, ansi-escape

I've been trying to format the output of SSH2->read() method. I tried using ANSI.php following
 http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top

My code

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('File/ANSI.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.106.240.212');
$ssh->login('Administrator', 'Nbv12345') or die("Login failed");
$ansi = new File_ANSI();

$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec("powershell.exe\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(2);
echo $ssh->read();
$ssh->write("ls\n");
echo $ssh->read();
?>
```

The output is full of ANSI characters and no 'ls' results

```
(B)0[?7l[H[J[1;1HWindows PowerShell[2;1HCopyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.[4;1HPS C:\Users\Administrator> (B)0[?7l[H[J[1;1H [2;1H [3;1H [4;1H [5;1H [6;1H [7;1H [8;1H [9;1H [10;1H [11;1H [12;1H [13;1H [14;1H [15;1H [16;1H [17;1H [18;1H [19;1H [20;1H [21;1H [22;1H [23;1H [24;1H [1;1HMicrosoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600][2;1H(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.[4;1HC:\Users\Administrator>ls[5;1H
```

I need something like this, Its not even close:[image]

How can I format this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're initializing the class doesn't mean you're including it lol. Try this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('File/ANSI.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.106.240.212');
$ssh->login('Administrator', 'Nbv12345') or die("Login failed");
$ansi = new File_ANSI();

$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec("powershell.exe\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(2);
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
$ssh->write("ls\n");
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo $ansi->getScreen();
?>
```

ie. wrap all your `$ssh->read()` calls in `$ansi->appendString()` and then do `$ansi->getScreen()`. Or maybe only wrap the `$ssh->read()` after `$ssh->write("ls\n")` in `$ansi->appendString()`. You could do `$ansi->getHistory()` too.

Comment: Hey Neubert, I tried it already. ANSI.php isn't able to parse few characters like (B and )0[  and the output is just the prompt. Nothing else!

`Notice: (B unsupported in C:\wamp\www\PT_TEST_FRAMEWORK\php\phpseclib\File\ANSI.php on line 434`

Comment: Could you post the full output (prior to your running it through File_ANSI) in a pastebin.com link?